# Finding and renaming filesystem entries with badly encoded names

Tags: filesystems

On various filesystems, I have a bunch of filesystem entries that have badly-encoded names (they were written with the wrong character encoding).

How can I automatically list all entries with names that are invalid for the current character encoding?

Having found all those entries, how can I automatically rename them all from one encoding to another?

Comment: It would help if you could let us know which filesystem in particular.

Comment: Or operating system at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply do a

```
convmv -r -f ASCII -t UTF-8 $targetdir
```

unless you add the *--notest* it won't actually do anything to your files. Defaults assume the from encoding is ASCII and to encoding is UTF-8. Pipe that thru *awk '{print $2}'* to only get the filenames that would be converted.

Note: I'm assuming you are using Linux. Most POSIX filesystems don't care about the encoding of filenames, however the [manpage of convmv](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=convmv&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+5.0+lenny&format=html&locale=en) has a couple of details (also how to decode double UTF-8 encoded filenames)

Comment: What does -f ASCII -t UTF-8 do? It looks like it would convert ASCII to UTF-8, which is a no-op, as ASCII is a subset of UFT-8.

Comment: That is correct but I rather give noop commands than kill someone elses box and take the blame for it. Thou convmv doesn't actually do anything without the --notest. But Murphey never sleeps :)